# Error: Secure Check Fail : aboot, when trying to update firmware on Samsung Galaxy Core Prime using Odin

Tags: updates, device-firmware, odin, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

The things I did to update firmware from Android 4.4.4 to 5.0.2:

1. Installed latest `Samsung usb drivers for mobiles`
2. Installed latest `Samsung kies` and through that I installed `device drivers.`
3. Downloaded Odin `v3.10.6`.
4. Put my phone in `odin mode`.
5. Connected my phone to my pc via original usb cable.
6. ODIN -> `AP` -> lollipop firmware (`G360FXXU1BOD9_G360FOXA1BOD9_G360FXXU1BOD9_HOME.tar.md5`) -> start.

After that this happened;

[image]
[image]

And my device showed this error in red color : `SECURE CHECK FAIL : aboot`.

Any suggestions, how can I get 5.0.2 lollipop on my `core prime`?

**Edit** : I recently put phone to format, then removed micro SD, and then did everything from step 4 but no luck. It's a new Samsung Galaxy Core Prime SM-G360F (nearly 5 days old).

Comment: Are you sure that the ROM you downloaded isn't corrupt? You can test to see if a file is corrupt by comparing its `md5` signature to the one on the server. Ask the ROM uploader if they can help.

Comment: Otherwise, it may be that the boot loader is utterly incompatible with your phone. You can't just put ROMs from other Samsung phones in to ODIN and think that it will work if that is the case.

Comment: @georgeunix no that is not the case, The name of the file clearly shows that. Also I (just to ensure) extracted the .tar.md5 file using 7z in some folder and the file got extracted without any errors.

Comment: I don't know what model number the Galaxy Prime is ;)

Comment: Are you sure your boot loader is unlocked?

Comment: how can I check that? name of the phone is given in edit at the last of this question

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I don't own a Samsung device any more.

Comment: wait while I search a li'll bit more

Comment: The issue is clearly with the connection to the phone's boot loader.

Comment: You might find that another distribution of ODIN, or even Heimdall or Mobile ODIN may work. ODIN is a leaked tool from Samsung which is buggy at best.

Comment: "*[Finally, the function performs signature verification of the entire image. If signature verification succeeds, the kernel is booted; otherwise, a tampering warning is displayed and the device fails to boot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EIfXa.png)*". Source: http://blog.azimuthsecurity.com/2013/05/exploiting-samsung-galaxy-s4-secure-boot.html

Comment: You didn't purchase your phone from a mobile network (or carrier), did you? Is there network branding on the phone or box? If so, many networks prevent you from interfering with their software. You may be able to research whether this may be a possibility.

Comment: bootloader unlocked means rooting phone? if that is so, then it is clearly mentioned that the phone should not be rooted

Comment: @georgeunix No, I don't think so, my phone is not network branded

Answer (score 4):

This indicates that you are using the wrong file for your phone model.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, as I am :), and I know people will say OMG don't do that, but Tmobile and International Variants can be interchanged, I've done it many times. But ODIN is stopping me.

Answer (score 2):

I used to get the same message. Then I removed an option called "sécurité Verr. de réactivation" in french. Translation may be "Reactivation Lock Security".
Uncheck it and restart root procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I have an imperfect solution!

If you can still get into your recovery module (TWRP in my case), then you can use a micro-sd card to flash a rom onto the device. In my case, I used CM 12 because I knew it would work, and I was freaking out, panicking that i had bricked it completely.

My experience was with a Galaxy Note 4 on T-Mobile. Hope this helps.

However, I am by no means an expert, so there is likely a better way.

Comment: I tried that too, btw I got it fixed by technician in 5 min who had original copy of the firmware. I don't know which answer to pick as right one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your download file is complete, remove `.md5` by renaming it. Try flashing afterwards, it wont calculate the checksum then.